# Count the number of unique values with at least k occurrences per group in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 3 columns that looks like this :

```
ID | obs_type | Value
1      A        0.1  
1      A        0.2
1      B        0.4
2      B        0.5
2      C        0.2
2      C        0.3
3      B        0.1
```

I want to have the count of IDs with at least k observations in each group Type.

In the example above, if k = 2 (at least 2 observations of the same ID to be counted), I would like to have :

```
obs_type | count
A            1
B            0
C            1
```

As there is a single ID with two observations of type A and single ID with two observations of type C.

There are no ID with two observations of type B.

For k = 1, I just do :

```
SELECT obs_type, COUNT(DISTINCT ID ) FROM table_x GROUP BY obs_type;
```

But I'm looking for a solution that would work for arbitrary k.

Thanks !!!!

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. Simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT ID)` to make code clearer.

Comment: Great, much better!

Comment: `having count(distinct id) >= k`?

Comment: For k = 2, how come you want 0 for B, and 1 for C?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I think this will only filter the obs_types that have at least k unique IDs. So this will return only B : 3.

Comment: @jarlh There is no ID that have two occurence of B. While ID 2 has two occurences of C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the aggregation in two steps:

k = 2 here:

```
select count(case when cnt >= 2 then cnt end), obs_type
from
(
    select count(*) cnt, obs_type
    from table_x
    group by id, obs_type
) dt
group by obs_type
```

The *derived table* (subquery) returns:

```
             cnt obs_type
================ ========
               2 A
               1 B
               1 B
               2 C
               1 B
```

Then use a `case` expression to do *conditional aggregation*, and you'll get:

```
SQL>select count(case when cnt >= 2 then cnt end), obs_type
SQL&from
SQL&(
SQL&    select count(*) cnt, obs_type
SQL&    from table_x
SQL&    group by id, obs_type
SQL&) dt
SQL&group by obs_type;
                     obs_type
==================== ========
                   1 A
                   0 B
                   1 C

                  3 rows found
```

Comment: In Postgres, I would recommend `count(*) filter (where cnt >= 2)`.